# The probability density function $f(x)$ of a random variable $X$ is symmetric about $0$. Then we have:

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

The pdf $f(x)$ of a random variable $X$ is symmetric about $0$. Then $\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(u)dudx= $?

My input:

$\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(u)dudx$

$\int_{-2}^{2}F(x)dx\ $

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform) tells that $F(x)\sim U(0,1)$

pdf=$f(F(x))=\dfrac{1}{1-0}$

Therefor

$\int_{-2}^{2}F(x)dx\ =4$

But this is wrong answer can someone help me here?

Edit : my friend solved this question as

CDF of Uniform distribution is 
$\frac{x-a}{b-a}$

$\int_{-2}^{2}F(x)dx\ =$
$\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{x+2}{4}\implies 2 $ (I don't know the reasoning that's how just he solved I am not in contact with him so if anyone can relate?)

Comment: The result you have linked to does not tell you that $F(x)$ is the uniform density; it tells you that if $X$ is a random variable with distribution $F$ then $F(X)$ is a random variable with uniform distribution. Also, the uniform density on $[0,1]$ is only equal to $1$  from $0$ to $1$. Outside $[0,1]$ the density has value zero, so you will not get $4$ when you integrate the uniform density from $-2$ to $2$ (you will get $1$ as you should).

Comment: @smcc but anyhow I 'll get pdf of $F(x)=1$ won't I?

Comment: I do not understand your question. What do you mean by "pdf of $F(x)=1$"?

Comment: @smcc Let $Z$ be a random variable . $Z=F(x)$ and $Z\sim U(0,1)$, $f_{Z}(z)=1$

Comment: @smcc It won't be $4$ I got it but what will be the pdf of $F(x)$?

Comment: It is not relevant to your problem. You are trying to integrate $F(x)$, not the pdf of $F(X)$.

Comment: @smcc Ohh i see so how will I proceed can you write answer please correct answer is $2$ I don't know how to reach there using $F(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(x)$ is an even function, $F(0)=\frac12$ and $F(x)-\frac12$ is an odd function. Then
$$\int_{-2}^2F(x)\,dx=\int_{-2}^2(F(x)-1/2)\,dx+\int_{-2}^2\frac12\,dx$$
Since the integral of an odd function from $-a$ to $a$ is zero:
$$=0+\int_{-2}^2\frac12\,dx=\frac12\cdot4=2$$
and the answer is 2.

Comment: Wow, that was smooth. Can you tell me what wrong in my intuition?

Comment: So what [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform) tells us ?

Comment: I don't get it someone showed me reaching the answer with the help this probability integral transformation.

Comment: No parcly, believe me, I am editing my question just check it out. It will give the same answer.I just couldn't figure out the reasoning behind it.

Comment: see I just edited my question

Comment: What is smcc saying can you argue with him on this topic?

Comment: I know but I am saying won't you argue with smcc ? I am still confused in your answer and his answer.

Comment: @Damn1o1 I don't have to.